# Popup Alert looops, how do i stop it to loop?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Im trying to have a button that triggers an alert pop-up with info from a variable. It does what it supposed to do, but it loops continuously. What have i done wrong :) ?

Here is what i have on the Client-Side:

```
 <button class="green" id="insert-text" onclick="ReadData()">Markera</button>

<script>
  function ReadData(data)
{
        alert(data);
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(ReadData)
      .GetDataFromSpreadsheet();
}
</script>
```

And here is what i have on the server-side:

```
function GetDataFromSpreadsheet()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = ss.getActiveRange();
  var value = range.getValues();

  return value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You pass the same function a  "withSuccessHandler" (creating an infinite loop :) ).
You need define an anonymous function:

```
function ReadData(data){
//   alert(data);   // not here :)
   google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(data){
      alert( data );
   }).GetDataFromSpreadsheet();
}
```

or declare a normal function:

```
function handleData( data ){
   alert( data );
}

// [...]
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler( handleData ).GetDataFromSpreadsheet();
// [...]
```

Regards,
Kevin